# Uso de "IF" con Comprension de Listas

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark

Tengo el siguiente DataFrame:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podrán observar la columna `hist_sol_folio` tiene un arreglo con varios elementos separado por comas. Lo que necesito hacer es lograr iterar sobre esa columna y si en algún registro encuentra el elemento `"QO"` que me devuelva un 1 en caso contario un `0`, para lo cual realice una comprensión de listas de la siguiente manera:

```
quebranto_lambda = lambda lista: [1 for i in lista if i == 'QO']
for i in claims.select('hist_sol_folio','issuing_entity_id').collect():
   print(i[1])
   print(i[0])
   print(quebranto_lambda(i[0]))
```

Dándome como salida:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo cual solo esta bien en parte, ya que si me regresa un `1` cuando encuentra el elemento `"QO"` pero me regresa una lista vacía en caso contrario, no un `0` como necesito.

¿Alguien sabe como podría complementar o cambiar el código? No es necesario que se use comprensión de listas, de hecho si me regresa solo el número (1 o 0) y no una lista es mejor pero a mi se me ocurrió hacerlo de esta forma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el fondo lo que quieres saber es simplemente si `'Q0'` está o no está en la lista, y esa información te la da el operador `in`:

```
'Q0' in lista
```

que te devolverá `True` si está, o `False` si no.

Si quieres que la respuesta sea 1 ó 0, basta sumar 0 a dicha respuesta, pues en ese caso Python se verá obligado, para hacer la suma, a tratar al booleano como un entero, para lo que convertirá `True` en 1 y `False` en 0 (y al sumarles 0 no cambia el resultado).

De modo que tu lambda podría ser:

```
quebranto_lambda = lambda lista: ('Q0' in lista) + 0
```

Comment: Para convertir de booleano a entero es mejor usar la función `int`: `int('Q0' in lista)`. Pero esta conversión depende de la implementación de los boleanos como subclase de los enteros. Me resulta contraria a la regla de ser explícito que tiene python, por lo que recomendaría más usar el operador ternario: `1 if 'Q0' in lista else 0`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, fueron de gran ayuda!!!!